# Java Node dynamic position on HBox

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I use certain events to place small rectangles on an HBox. Their placement is perfect when the window has not been resized, but when you for example go from small to fullscreen, their placement is wrong (of course, because they get a certain value for X at the time of placement - this is measured by getting the width of the HBox at that specific moment).

**Question:**

How can I make these positions dynamic, so when I resize the window, they stay in proportion?

**Pictures:**
[image: Normal view]
[image: Fullscreen]

**Code:**

```
@FXML HBox tagLine; // initializes the HBox

...

public void addTag(String sort) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, tagLine.getHeight());
    double pos = timeSlider.getValue() / 100 * tagLine.getWidth(); // retrieves position at the moment of being called
    rect.setTranslateX(pos);
    rect.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            showNotification("Gemarkeerde gebeurtenis: " + sort);
        }
    });
    rect.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            notificationHide.play();
        }
    });

    tagLine.getChildren().add(rect);
}
```

Comment: How do you position the rect in the HBox? margin? putting a Node to the left of it? `translateX`?

Comment: You need to show us some code. Just edit your question and add the logic that you are currently using for translating the rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things that you need to take into account while translating a shape with *accountable* size is that you need to :

- Translate the shape from its center
- If the translation is dependent on the width of a Node, listen to the changes made to the with of that particular node and make changes to the translate property accordingly

Both of the above points seem to be missing in your implementation. You are never listening to width property of `HBox`. Neither is your calculation for `pos` taking the center of Rectangle into account.

Here is an example which try to keep the Rectangle at the center no matter what the size of your HBox is.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final int SIDE = 40;
    private static final double DEFAULT_WIDTH = 200;
    private static final double DEFAULT_POSITION = 100;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(SIDE, SIDE);
        HBox root = new HBox(rectangle);
        root.setPrefWidth(DEFAULT_WIDTH);

        rectangle.translateXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().multiply(DEFAULT_POSITION/DEFAULT_WIDTH).subtract(SIDE/2));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]